# Creating a Label from a thread in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing a program, where I want a thread to create a Label and add it to a window in tkinter. Below is an abstracted version of my code. The Label does not show in the window. The thing that has me confused though, is that if if I have something like self.window.geometry("900x900") in the render function, the window will be updated. Why can the shape of the window be updated but not a Label? I've also tried using the update() function in render but to no avail. Thanks in advance.

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading

class Game(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.gui = GUI()
  
    def run():
        while True:
           #  some code
           self.gui.render()

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, game_board):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.geometry("500x500")
    
    def render():
        img = tk.PhotoImage(file="image.png")
        label = tk.Label(self.window, image=img)
        label.pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    g = Game()
    g.start()
    g.gui.window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I would expect that this program, if it does anything at all when ignoring the requirement to do all Tkinter calls from the main thread, to produce a `NameError: window` when you try to create a Label - that should be `self.window`.  And the Label is going to be blank, because you didn't save a reference to the image being displayed.

Comment: There are few issues in your code: 1) create instance of `GUI` without passing the required argument `game_board`; 2) `window` in `label = tk.Label(window, image=img)` should be `self.window`; 3) image created in a function without keeping a reference, so the image will be garbage collected after function returns (*it is the reason why you don't see the label*); 4) keep creating new labels because `render()` is executed inside a infinite while loop.

Comment: I did forget to make it self.window in the example. I made the edit. And sorry, what do you mean by a reference here?

Comment: @acw1668, @jasonharper you guys are right. I should have made ``img`` part of the class. I can now see the image. Thank you!